# To ask for a PostDoc position in the university X, is better to do it by myself or to ask to my supervisor?

Tags: postdocs, career-path

I am a PhD student in **artificial intelligence** from an European university. This year I am going to finish my PhD program, so I am looking around to search for a **suitable Postdoc position**.

I would like to apply to an important American university, named X.
In my research group here I have important professors that follow my work. One is my supervisor, an expert of artificial intellingence, and follows my work. The other is an expert of **operating systems** (i.e. different field from artificial intelligence).

This operating system professor in the 90s spent some years **working at the preminent university X**, and he still has a lot of contact and collaborations in that field.

**Should I take advantage of this and ask him to contact my potential Postdoc advisor at the university to which I want to apply, even if he is from a different field?**
Would it be worth?

His mail would be something like "Some decades ago I worked at your university in the operating systems field, and now I would like to recommed this candidate from artificial intelligence..."
Would this have **sense**?
Would this be **useful**?

Or would it be better that I **contacted personally by myself** this professor for the Postdoc position?

Comment: I would do it by myself, then after sometime ask my advisor if he's willing to send a follow up message.

Answer (score 16):

Put yourself in the shoes of the professor: what would they like best in a candidate? Contacting them yourself demonstrates more commitment than having your advisor do it for you. There may be cases where an introduction by a third party is best, but it seems to me it's better to use that only if really needed: guy is a superstar, your introductee knows him very well, or you are just trying to strategically probe whether a candidature would be well-received without actually getting involved yourself.

Also, you can get your advisor to follow up if you don't receive an answer, or just to help you when/if they are contacted as a reference.

Comment: On the other hand, you should name-drop your local faculty colleagues ("I am working with professors X and Y." or "My thesis committee member Prof Z suggested that I contact you.") when you contact potential postdoc advisors.  But ask your local faculty _in advance_ for permission to be name-dropped, since you're effectively using them as references.

Comment: @JeffE yes, very true

Comment: Another good one is "Professor X suggested I contact you...."

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about having a professor contacting someone on your behalf, which is generally good and positive.

There are other similar notions you may have preferred to ask that have formal terms:

- "Should I ask my supervisor to write a **letter of recommendation** for me, even though they are not from my field?"  to which, the answer is *absolutely*. You usually get several letters. It would be prudent to consider that a writer who knows your audience will be particularly influential.
- "Should I ask for **an introduction** from my supervisor?"- This is also very common, but less formal than a letter. Your supervisor, if he gets along with you and has contacts in the right area, can send an email and CC you on it. You ask/answer questions and can passively demonstrate that you are amiable and intelligent.

I would recommend doing either or both of these things, so long as you are sensitive to a polite refusal by your advisor. They may not have the positive relationships you think they have, and do not want to embarrass you by a negative association.